# How to check if firebase task is complete in Java?

Tags: java, firebase, task, firebase-authentication

I have a Java Web application with Tomcat 8 (not android), Java 8 and Firebase Admin version 5.2.0. 
The below code works fine however I need to be sure that task is complete and return a value.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/verifyToken")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response verifyToken(@Context HttpHeaders headers,@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            String auth = headers.getRequestHeader("authorization").get(0);

            if (!auth.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("logged auth token: " + auth);
            }

            // validate token
            Task<FirebaseToken> task = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(auth)

            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                @Override

                public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decoded) {
                    String uid = decoded.getUid();
                    //do some stuff

                }
        });
            /*
             The return statement below shouldn't run unless "task" is 
             complete.
              task has method isComplete()
            */
            return Response.status(200).entity(user).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Login Exception " + e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }

    }
```

Task object (task) has a method "isComplete()". However, it may need to be called more than once. If in first time the task is not complete, the code should know how to wait and call it again later and this way on until certain number of times.

I'm stuck in how to build the logic to properly wait and try again until task is  complete or event quit the condition.

How to do it?

Comment: You're looking for `Tasks.await()`. See Doug'd excellent blog post here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Frank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend you check out Doug Stevenson's excellent series of blog posts on the `Task` API. This specific problem is covered in https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html

The solution seems to be `Tasks.await(task)...`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, Frank.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using Tasks.await() to wait firebase task finish.
example in kotlin to get token:

```
var  task = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener {}
Tasks.await(task)
var token = task.result!!.token
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks